# How to Break Up R Data Frame by Variable Value

Tags: r, dataframe

I feel like this is an incredibly basic question, yet after some extensive searching I haven't found an answer that works for my specific situation (all the situations I found were a bit more complicated than mine and the solutions didn't work for me). I have a data frame where the last column is just a 0 or a 1. I want to split up this data frame into two data frames based on the value of the third column, so all the rows with a 0 in the last column are in one data frame, and all the rows with a 1 in the last column are in the other data frame. I would also like to keep the original column titles in both data frames.

Answer (score 0):

Replace below var3 by the name of your thord variable or use `data[, 3]` instead of `data$var3`.

```
data0 <- data[data$var3 == 0, ]
data1 <- data[data$var3 == 1, ]
```

You should read the subsetting chapter of Hadley Wickham's "Advanced R" book available here: http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Subsetting.html

Answer (score 0):

you could also use `split()` like so:

```
split(x = iris, f = iris$Species)
```

this will give you a list of data frames.